# A script and keybindings to look for VIM commands in a file, and then execute them on that file

Tags: formatting

This is a followup question to [Auto sorting of lists of include files](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/6305/auto-sorting-of-lists-of-include-files), which explains the motivation.

**EDIT**
I am looking for a script and/or keybindings to look for VIM commands in a file, and then execute them on that file. As mentioned in the referenced question, the idea is that the script and the key bound to it, will do the following:
Look for lines that obey a certain patter in a file.
E.g.,

```
'// vim: some vim command
```

and execute these in sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution is to add the following lines to your `.vimrc`

```
" mapping to execute the function
nmap <F4> :call ExecuteCommandsFromFile()<CR>

function! ExecuteCommandsFromFile()
    " The pattern which will indicate the commands
    let l:pattern="'// vim: "
    let l:res=1

    " Go to the first line of the file
    normal gg

    " While some commands are found in the file
    while search(l:pattern, "We") != 0

        " Get the position of the text representing the command
        let l:start=col('.')
        let l:end=col('$')

        " Get the command
        let l:line=strpart(getline('.'), l:start, l:end)

        " Execute the command
        execute l:line
    endwhile

endfunction
```

**Notes**

- You can replace `<F4>` by any key you want to use to start the function
- The variable `l:pattern` can be changed to match the pattern you'll use to indicate that the line contains a command to execute
- The `search` command in the `while`loop uses the flag `W` not to wrap around the file and thus executing the commands only once.

**Edit**

I made this according to what I understood from the question but if the solution doesn't really fit your needs don't hesitate to give more details so that I can adapt the solution.

**Edit 2**

I thought it could be interesting to execute the commands after parsing all the file instead of executing it as soon as the command is read. So here is a second version where the function firstly get all the commands and then execute them:

```
function! ExecuteCommandsFromFile2()
    " The pattern which will indicate the commands
    let l:pattern="'// vim: "
    let l:res=1

    " Go to the first line of the file
    normal gg

    " The list will contain the commands to execute
    let l:commands = []

    " While some commands are found in the file
    while search(l:pattern, "We") != 0

        " Get the position of the text representing the command
        let l:start=col('.')
        let l:end=col('$')

        " Get the command
        let l:line=strpart(getline('.'), l:start, l:end)

        " Add the command to the list
        call add(l:commands, l:line)
    endwhile

    " Execute each command
    for l:command in l:commands
        execute l:command
    endfor
endfunction
```

A possible evolution would be to refactor both of the function to get only one accepting an argument describing the mode to use...