# Prevent Vim from breaking up inline code blocks in (r)markdown

Tags: wrapping, filetype-markdown

I edit R-markdown files a lot, and this entails writing inline code blocks, such as

```
`r sum(mylongvectorname)`
```

I usually have my text hard-wrapped at 80 chars, and this causes problems for the inline blocks, since they aren't allowed to split. I found the answer for [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/564/prevent-vim-from-breaking-up-links-mid-tag-in-markdown/649#649) helpful in preventing the split from happening when writing in insert mode.

However, if I want to wrap a paragraph in normal mode with  <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>, the r inline code is split. Is there any solution that would allow me to wrap the paragraph by <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> and

a) leave the lines with `r .* ` untouched

or (better)

b) treat  `r .* ` as a single word so that if it is moved, the whole block is moved together